# Why is int rather than unsigned int used for C and C++ for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, int, unsigned

This is a rather silly question but why is `int` commonly used instead of `unsigned int` when defining a for loop for an array in C or C++?

```
for(int i;i<arraySize;i++){}
for(unsigned int i;i<arraySize;i++){}
```

I recognize the benefits of using `int` when doing something other than array indexing and the benefits of an iterator when using C++ containers. Is it just because it does not matter when looping through an array? Or should I avoid it all together and use a different type such as `size_t`?

Comment: It's less to write.

Comment: It's like why do you not call other person with first and last names all the time but just call them by their first name?

Comment: Actually for indexes I prefer to use `size_t`, which is guaranteed to be big enough and is much less typing than `unsigned int`.

Comment: A very good article that explains why do we need `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/

Comment: @Blagovest: The motivation part of that article is good, but the rest of it is full of misinformation (equivalence of types, ability to store pointers in `size_t`, etc.) and completely glosses over the signed overflow and range issues with `ptrdiff_t`. I would hesitate to call it "very good"..

Comment: `unsigned` is the same as `usigned int`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a more general phenomenon, often people don't use the correct types for their integers. Modern C has semantic typedefs that are much preferable over the primitive integer types. E.g everything that is a "size" should just be typed as `size_t`. If you use the semantic types systematically for your application variables, loop variables come much easier with these types, too.

And I have seen several bugs that where difficult to detect that came from using `int` or so. Code that all of a sudden crashed on large matrixes and stuff like that. Just coding correctly with correct types avoids that.

Comment: The correct type for a size is `size_t`, unfortunately `size_t` has been defined using a wrong type itself (unsigned) and this is the source of a big number of bugs. I prefer using semantically correct types for the code (e.g. `int`) than using formally correct but semantically wrong types. With `int`s you may run into bugs for very large (incredibly large) values... with `unsigned` values the crazy behavior is much closer to everyday use (0).

Comment: @6502, opinions seems to vary a lot on that. You could have a look at my blog post about that: http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/a-praise-of-size_t-and-other-unsigned-types/

Comment: @JensGustedt: that the semantic is wrong is not an opinion, unless you think it's correct that `a.size() - b.size()` should be about four billions when `b` has one element and `a` has none. That someone thinks that `unsigned` is a fantastic idea for non-negative numbers you're correct, but my impression is that they put too much weight on the name rather on the real meaning. Among the ones that think that unsigned is a bad idea for counters and indexes is Bjarne Stroustrup... see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10168079/320726

Comment: @6502, as I said, opinions vary a lot. And SO shouldn't be a place to discuss opinions, especially of people not involved in the discussion themselves. Stroustrup is certainly a reference for many things, but not for C.

Comment: @6502 Sorry, but the semantics you think are correct are not. size_t - size_t should be off_t, not size_t.

Comment: @MilesRout: not sure what you're talking about. Are you saying that is logically correct that `a.size()-b.size()` should be four billions when `a` has two elements and `b` has three elements? This happens in C++ simply because `size_t` is an unsigned type and choosing such a type for container size was a logical mistake that cannot be fixed now. If you say that the difference of two "non-negative" values should be a "possibly negative" value then I agree... but non-negative and unsigned are very different concepts and in C++ the difference of two unsigned is unsigned.

Comment: @6502 No, I'm saying that it's absurd to claim that 'unsigned' and 'nonnegative' are different concepts. They're the same concept. The issue is not unsigned. The issue is that the subtraction of two unsigned values should be signed. `a.size()` should be `size_t`, but `a.size() - b.size()` should be `ptrdiff_t`, just as the subtraction of two pointers doesn't give you a pointer, but a `ptrdiff_t`. A pointer is, after all, basically the same as a `size_t`.

Comment: @MilesRout: `unsigned` has a very precise meaning in C++ and that meaning is unrelated to "non-negative". May be you like the **name** of the type, but the name is irrelevant and what counts is the semantic. `unsigned` means "modulo integer" or "bitmask" ... and saying that the size of a container should be a modulo integer or a bitmask is the error that was made long ago and that unfortunately there's no way to fix now. More details on why unsigned is different from "non-negative" on this video... https://youtu.be/4afySnY-XgY

Answer (score 44):

Using `int` is more correct from a logical point of view for indexing an array.

`unsigned` semantic in C and C++ doesn't really mean "not negative" but it's more like "bitmask" or "modulo integer".

To understand why `unsigned` is not a good type for a "non-negative" number please consider these totally absurd statements:

- Adding a possibly negative integer to a non-negative integer you get a non-negative integer
- The difference of two non-negative integers is always a non-negative integer
- Multiplying a non-negative integer by a negative integer you get a non-negative result

Obviously none of the above phrases make any sense... but it's how C and C++ `unsigned` semantic indeed works.

Actually using an `unsigned` type for the size of containers is a design mistake of C++ and unfortunately we're now doomed to use this wrong choice forever (for backward compatibility). You may like the name "unsigned" because it's similar to "non-negative" but the name is irrelevant and what counts is the semantic... and `unsigned` is very far from "non-negative".

For this reason when coding most loops on vectors my personally preferred form is:

```
for (int i=0,n=v.size(); i<n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

(of course assuming the size of the vector is not changing during the iteration and that I actually need the index in the body as otherwise the `for (auto& x : v)...` is better).

This running away from `unsigned` as soon as possible and using plain integers has the advantage of avoiding the traps that are a consequence of `unsigned size_t` design mistake. For example consider:

```
// draw lines connecting the dots
for (size_t i=0; i<pts.size()-1; i++) {
    drawLine(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
}
```

the code above will have problems if the `pts` vector is empty because `pts.size()-1` is a huge nonsense number in that case. Dealing with expressions where `a < b-1` is not the same as `a+1 < b` even for commonly used values is like dancing in a minefield.

Historically the justification for having `size_t` unsigned is for being able to use the extra bit for the values, e.g. being able to have 65535 elements in arrays instead of just 32767 on 16-bit platforms. In my opinion even at that time the extra cost of this wrong semantic choice was not worth the gain (and if 32767 elements are not enough now then 65535 won't be enough for long anyway).

Unsigned values are great and very useful, but NOT for representing container size or for indexes; for size and index regular signed integers work much better because the semantic is what you would expect.

Unsigned values are the ideal type when you need the modulo arithmetic property or when you want to work at the bit level.

Comment: I think you are right because java (a "improved" c++) not support unsigned int. Also I think the correct way of write that line is: size_t arr_index;
for (size_t i=1; i<=pts.size(); i++) {
 arr_index = i - 1;
}

Comment: @carlos: No. That **would** be the correct way if `size_t` would have been defined correctly. Unfortunately a design error made `size_t` an `unsigned` and therefore those values ended up having bitmask semantic. Unless you think that's correct that the size of a container is a bitmask then using `size_t` is the wrong choice. A choice that unfortunately was made by the standard C++ library, but no one forces me to repeat the same error in my code. My suggestion is to just run away from `size_t` and use regular ints as soon as you can instead of beding logic so that it works also with `size_t`.

Comment: It's not just 16-bit platforms. With current `size_t` you can use e.g. `vector<char>` of size e.g. 2.1G on IA-32 Linux with 3G/1G memory split. If `size_t` were signed, what would be if you increase your vector from <2G to a bit more? Suddenly the size will become negative. This just doesn't make any sense. The language should not impose such artificial limits.

Comment: @Ruslan: it's amazing how this very weak argument can stick even with reasonably good programmers: the idea of a single array containing single bytes eating up most of your address space is totally absurd and I'm sure not something that faces up often yet apparently is considered very important by "unsigned for size" zealots. It would have been nice to have a data type with the ability to use all the bits and with the semantic of a "non-negative" integer, but unfortunately no such a type exist in C++ and using unsigned instead of that is nonsense.

Comment: @6502 see [this code](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/blob/master/plugins/DebuggerCore/unix/linux/PlatformProcess.cpp#L222) for an example of hack one needs to implement when an offset type is signed (here `off_t`/`off64_t` – not exactly C++, but related: POSIX). Not too inefficient, of course, but ugly. And this code is not of theoretical need there: it was implemented out of necessity.

Comment: @Ruslan: you mean that code was used to seek into a file bigger than 8 exabytes and so they found a bug?

Comment: @6502 18 exabytes actually. You see, `/proc/<pid>/mem` file on x86_64 Linux for 64-bit processes does have valid pages in the "negative" address range – namely, `[vsyscall]` at `0xffffffffff600000`. See the [original EDB issue](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/issues/399) that was fixed by the code.

Comment: @Ruslan: using an `unsigned` type of the exact size for addresses in an address space may make sense indeed. However it does **NOT** make sense having an `unsigned` type to represent the number of elements inside a container (what `std::` containers do).

Comment: I know you invested a lot in this answer and I appreciate your effort and examples. Unfortunately the answer is incorrect and the `unsigned size_t` design was the logical and obvious choice (and **not** a mistake). I added my own answer to explain further. Of course, you're free to disagree and downvote my answer).

Comment: @Myst: I'm old enough to tolerate knowing that someone is wrong on the internet and still sleep well. You are wrong and apparently don't even understand what overflow is for C++. A few years ago I've made a (bad) video to explain in more detail why "non-negative" and "unsigned" are two very different concepts that apparently you are confusing and about what "overflow" means. If you can tolerate strong italian accent and terrible audio this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4afySnY-XgY

Comment: I loved the video and the analogy to the analog clock. However, this ignores the fact that **all** mathematics on a limited number of bits (i.e., 32 bits) is modular. The only difference is that on signed integers you get undefined behavior once you hid the modular limit (overflow) and on unsigned integers you know what you're dealing with (wraparound) and you can handle the edge cases. I personally agree with the school of thought that believes that Bjarne was mistaken about this one.

Comment: @Myst: You still apparently do not understand what undefined behavior means. Signed arithmetic is NOT modular for C++. It's modular for most processors, that's true, but not for C++. For example a C++ compiler will assume that `(a < a+1)` is always true for signed integers, because it's true when you're not overflowing and what happens when you do is irrelevant because that is UB. This is not a bug, it's C++. UB is kind of a weird beast (and getting worse every year) and can even travel back in time... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: I agree and this is exactly the problem. Signed arithmetics is not **necessarily** modular, even though it is **limited** to the number of bits that the type holds... which means that **once the limit is reached, you get UB**. The compiler might optimize away the code, or you get infinite loops. Even if the code runs, on some CPUs you get a TRAP on others modular behavior. With signed integers you **do not know** what you get. That's why they should be avoided for all arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Myst: "crazy" behavior of signed integers happens at around 2 billions, a number that is rarely found in code. "crazy" behavior of unsigned integers happens around 0, probably the numeric value that is used most in programming (especially with containers). It would have been nice if C++ had a "non-negative" type for sizes, with proper semantic (e.g. that the subtraction of two non-negative integers is a possibly-negative integer), unfortunately no such a type exist in C++. Wrap-around is ok and useful when you're looking for wrap-around, not for container size.

Comment: I do not know if 2Gb is such a rare indexing space for the type of systems that C++ code is used on... for me it sounds silly if I opened a file and my index would cause UB at 2Gb. Besides, it's not about what's "rare" it's about what's **correct**. All computers are designed to use modular math. The illusion that math is not modular of a limited precision machine is a cause for errors and part of the reason people mislabel C++ as unsafe, causing things like [this](https://media.defense.gov/2022/Nov/10/2003112742/-1/-1/0/CSI_SOFTWARE_MEMORY_SAFETY.PDF).

Answer (score 5):

It's purely laziness and ignorance. You should always use the right types for indices, and unless you have further information that restricts the range of possible indices, `size_t` is the right type.

Of course if the dimension was read from a single-byte field in a file, then you know it's in the range 0-255, and `int` would be a perfectly reasonable index type. Likewise, `int` would be okay if you're looping a fixed number of times, like 0 to 99. But there's still another reason not to use `int`: if you use `i%2` in your loop body to treat even/odd indices differently, `i%2` is a lot more expensive when `i` is signed than when `i` is unsigned...

Comment: see #3 on my answer, its not "purely" laziness/ignorance

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the code is wrong. Here's one way to fix it: `for (size_t i=10; i-->0; )`

Answer (score 4):

Not much difference. One benefit of `int` is it being signed. Thus `int i < 0` makes sense, while `unsigned i < 0` doesn't much.

If indexes are calculated, that may be beneficial (for example, you might get cases where you will never enter a loop if some result is negative).

And yes, it is less to write :-)

Comment: `typedef unsigned us;` and it's more to write.

Comment: @WTP - you're one of those who will not understand sarcasm even with the ":-)" right next to it? Well, I guess no cure there...

Comment: A negative size or negative index makes no sense

Comment: @MilesRout: An attempt to operate on a negative number of items will generally have different implications from an attempt to operate on a really large positive number of items.  If a function which is supposed to operate all but the last item of a collection is passed a collection with no items, having the number of items to process be recognizable as -1 seems cleaner than having it be SIZE_MAX.

Answer (score 2):

Using `int` to index an array is legacy, but still widely adopted. `int` is just a generic number type and does not correspond to the addressing capabilities of the platform. In case it happens to be shorter or longer than that, you may encounter strange results when trying to index a very large array that goes beyond.

On modern platforms, `off_t`, `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` guarantee much more portability.

Another advantage of these types is that they give *context* to someone who reads the code. When you see the above types you know that the code will do array subscripting or pointer arithmetic, not just any calculation.

So, if you want to write bullet-proof, portable and context-sensible code, you can do it at the expense of a few keystrokes.

GCC even supports a `typeof` extension which relieves you from typing the same typename all over the place:

```
typeof(arraySize) i;

for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Then, if you change the type of `arraySize`, the type of `i` changes automatically.

Comment: Though to be fair, on all but the most obscure 32- and 64-bit platforms, you'd need at least 4 billion elements for such issues to show up. And platforms with smaller `int`s typically have far less memory as well, making `int` sufficient in general.

Comment: @delnan: It's not so simple. This kind of reasoning has led to very serious vulnerabilities in the past, even by folks who think of themselves as security gods like DJB...

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the coder. Some coders prefer type perfectionism, so they'll use whatever type they're comparing against. For example, if they're iterating through a C string, you might see:

```
size_t sz = strlen("hello");
for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
    ...
}
```

While if they're just doing something 10 times, you'll probably still see `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `int` cause it requires less physical typing and it doesn't matter - they take up the same amount of space, and unless your array has a few billion elements you won't overflow if you're not using a 16-bit compiler, which I'm usually not.

Comment: Not using an `int` also gives more context about the variable and can be regarded as self-documenting code. Also have a read here: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0050/

Answer (score 0):

Because unless you have an array with size bigger than two gigabyts of type `char`, or 4 gigabytes of type `short` or 8 gigabytes of type `int` etc, it doesn't really matter if the variable is signed or not.

So, why type more when you can type less?

Comment: But then, if `arraySize` is variable and you want to write bullet-proof code, `off_t`, `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` still carry some significance.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely necessary if you MAY have such super huge arrays, but since people normally don't, then they just use the simple-to-write `int`. For example, if you are sorting an array of `int` with O(n^2), you basically have to wait forever for the array to be sorted if there are more than 2M elements, that is given if you even have 8GB of memory. So you see, usually even if you make the indexing right, most programs are useless when given input THAT large. So why make them bullet-proof?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Most of us would find it just unfortunate if passing a giant array made the sort take weeks to complete, but would find it completely unacceptable when passing a giant array yields a root shell.

Comment: @R.. don't get me wrong, I'm not saying this is good, I'm answering the question that asks why people use `int` all the time.

Comment: I was responding to your most recent comment.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue that it's shorter to type, the reason is that it allows negative numbers.

Since we can't say in advance whether a value can ever be negative, most functions that take integer arguments take the signed variety. Since most functions use signed integers, it is often less work to use signed integers for things like loops. Otherwise, you have the potential of having to add a bunch of typecasts.

As we move to 64-bit platforms, the unsigned range of a signed integer should be more than enough for most purposes. In these cases, there's not much reason not to use a signed integer.

Comment: Negative values are a key point, and yours is the only answer that makes more than a token mention of that. But, sadly there're implicit Standard conversions between signed and unsigned parameter types that mean mixing them can just stuff up rather than the inconvenient but safe scenario you describe of "having to add a bunch of typecasts". And "As we move to 64-bit platforms, the unsigned range of a signed integer..." isn't actually growing for most compiler/OSes - `int`s still tend to be 32 bits, with `long`s moving from 32 to 64.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simple example:

```
int max = some_user_input; // or some_calculation_result
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    do_something;
```

If `max` happens to be a negative value, say -1, the `-1` will be regarded as `UINT_MAX` (when two integers with the sam rank but different sign-ness are compared, the signed one will be treated as an unsigned one). On the other hand, the following code would not have this issue:

```
int max = some_user_input;
for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    do_something;
```

Give a negative `max` input, the loop will be safely skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Using a signed `int` is - in most cases - **a mistake** that could easily result in potential bugs as well as undefined behavior.

Using `size_t` matches the system's word size (64 bits on 64 bit systems and 32 bits on 32 bit systems), always allowing for the correct range for the loop and minimizing the risk of an integer overflow.

The `int` recommendation comes to solve an issue where **reverse** `for` loops were often written incorrectly by unexperienced programmers (of course, `int` might not be in the correct range for the loop):

```c
/* a correct reverse for loop */
for (size_t i = count; i > 0;) {
   --i; /* note that this is not part of the `for` statement */
   /* code for loop where i is for zero based `index` */
}
/* an incorrect reverse for loop (bug on count == 0) */
for (size_t i = count - 1; i > 0; --i) {
   /* i might have overflowed and undefined behavior occurs */
}
```

In general, signed and unsigned variables shouldn't be mixed together, so at times using an `int` in unavoidable. However, the correct type for a `for` loop is **as a rule `size_t`**.

There's a nice talk about this misconception that signed variables are better than unsigned variables, you can find it on [YouTube (Signed Integers Considered Harmful by Robert Seacord)](https://youtu.be/Fa8qcOd18Hc).

**TL;DR;**: Signed variables are more dangerous and require more code than unsigned variables (which should be preferred almost in all cases and definitely whenever negative values aren't logically expected).

With unsigned variables the only concern is the overflow boundary which has a strictly defined behavior (wrap-around) and uses clearly defined modular mathematics.

This allows a single edge case test to catch an overflow and that test can be performed **after** the mathematical operation was executed.

However, with signed variables the overflow behavior is **undefined** (UB) and the negative range is actually larger than the positive range - things that add edge cases that must be tested for and explicitly handled **before** the mathematical operation can be executed.

i.e., how much `INT_MIN * -1`? (the pre-processor will protect you, but without it you're in a jam).

P.S.

As for the example offered by @6502 in their answer, the whole thing is again an issue of trying to cut corners and a simple missing `if` statement.

When a loop assumes at least 2 elements in an array, this assumption should be tested beforehand. i.e.:

```cpp
// draw lines connecting the dots - forward loop
if(pts.size() > 1) { // first make sure there's enough dots
  for (size_t i=0; i < pts.size()-1; i++) { // then loop
    drawLine(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
  }
}
// or test against i + 1 : which tests the desired pts[i+1]
for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < pts.size(); i++) { // then loop
  drawLine(pts[i], pts[i+1]);
}
// or start i as 1 : but note that `-` is slower than `+`
for (size_t i = 1; i < pts.size(); i++) { // then loop
  drawLine(pts[i - 1], pts[i]);
}
```