# Find matching consecutive integers in array

Tags: c, arrays

Given two arrays containing integers, figure out whether or not three consecutive integers are present in both arrays.
For example: A = [1, 4, 5, 7, 2] and B = [3, 1, 4, 5, 9] will result in "true" / 1 because [1, 4, 5] is present in both arrays.

My solution to this task is present below, but I feel like there must be a more optimized solution than this.

```
int consecutiveInts(int *a, int sizeA, int *b, int sizeB){
    int i, j;

    // Iterate over every integer in array b for every integer in array a.
    for (i = 0 ; i < sizeA - 2 ; i++){
        for (j = 0 ; j < sizeB - 2 ; j++){
            if (a[i] == b[j] && a[i + 1] == b[j + 1] && a[i + 2] == b[j + 2])
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would put some test before the loops so that it does not loop uselessly. Checking if A and B size are bigger than 3 for example.

Comment: You might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: Use dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small arrays, OP approach is OK.  For array lengths `m,n` it has `O(m*n)` run time.

An alternate makes 2 value arrays, sorts them and then looks for a common element.  It has `O(m*log2(m) + n*log2(n))` run time.  Certainly faster with large arrays than OP's code.

```
typedef struct {
  int i[3];
} int3;

void Init3(int3 *i3, const int *i, size_t n) {
  while (n--) {
    i3[n].i[0] = i[n];
    i3[n].i[1] = i[n + 1];
    i3[n].i[2] = i[n + 2];
  }
}

int fcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  return memcmp(a, b, sizeof (int3));
}

bool Pattern3(const int *a, size_t size_a, const int *b, size_t size_b) {
  if (size_a < 3 || size_b < 3) return false;

  int3 a3[size_a - 2];
  Init3(a3, a, size_a - 2);
  qsort(a3, size_a - 2, sizeof *a3, fcmp);

  int3 b3[size_b - 2];
  Init3(b3, b, size_b - 2);
  qsort(b3, size_b - 2, sizeof *b3, fcmp);

  while (size_a && size_b) {
    int cmp = fcmp(&a[size_a - 1], &b[size_b - 1]);
    if (cmp == 0) return true;
    if (cmp > 0) size_a--;
    else size_b--;
  }
  return false;
}

int main() {
  int A[] = { 1, 4, 5, 7, 2 };
  int B[] = { 3, 1, 4, 5, 9 };
  printf("%d\n", Pattern3(A, sizeof A / sizeof *A, B, sizeof B / sizeof *B));
}
```

An alternative would use a `bsearch()` rather than form the 2nd `int3 b3[]/qsort()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I cannot be wrong by sayin that declaring i and j outside of the loop is useless and not optimized.

Something like :

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeA - 2; i++) // i will only exist inside the loop
```

Would be a little better. 
I use unsigned type because it is a habit I have taken when using an iterating variable. I think this is a matter which, if you are interested and not already informed, you could learn from by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488837/why-is-int-rather-than-unsigned-int-used-for-c-and-c-for-loops) topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it optimizes running speed, but I notice that in case there are repeated numbers you don't need to check them over and over again.

For example three sequential elements in the first array are all `1`. After checking `a[i]` and seeing it's a mismatch you can skip directly to `a[i + 3]` without comparing `a[i + 1]` or `a[i + 2]` (they are also a mismatch).

The management of this condition, particularly if it's a short sequence of repeats, may not improve running time. You have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

With code changes that do not affect the [order of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), any candidate improvements need *profiling* (tests that measure the performance) to verify.

The following is still a O(n*m), yet with reduced coefficient as it can step through `b[]` faster if `a[]` has repeated values that also exist in `b[]`.  This speeds the inner `b[]` loop where the majority of time is consumed.

---

Look at the `a[]` pattern for distinct values to so `j` may be advanced faster.
Example:

```
#define x 0
bool Pattern3(const int *a, size_t size_a, const int *b, size_t size_b) {
  static const unsigned char deltas[2][2][2][2] = { //
      //                 What type of pattern is a[0], a[1], a[2]?
      { { { 1, 1 },   // X Y Z
      { 1, 1 } },     // X Y Y
      { { 1, 2 },     // X Y X
      { x, x } } },   // not possible
      { { { 2, 1 },   // X X Y
      { x, x } },     // not possible
      { { x, x },     // not possible
      { 2, 3 } } } }; // X X X
  for (unsigned i = 0; i + 2 < size_a; i++) {
    const unsigned char *delta23 = deltas[a[0] == a[1]][a[0] == a[2]][a[1] == a[2]];
    for (unsigned j = 0; j + 2 < size_b;) {
      if (a[0] != b[j]) {
        j++;
      } else if (a[0 + 1] != b[j + 1]) {
        j += delta23[0];
      } else if (a[0 + 2] != b[j + 2]) {
        j += delta23[1];
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    a++;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

Other minor changes which may help.

In the above, swap `a,b` when `size_a > size_b`.

Use `const` as lesser compilers can optimized on that.

```
// int consecutiveInts(int *a, int sizeA, int *b, int sizeB){
int consecutiveInts(const int *a, int sizeA, const int *b, int sizeB){
```

Iterate from 2.  Adjust indexing accordingly.

```
for (i = 2 ; i < sizeA ; i++){
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

try using the following loop

```
for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++)
    {
        if(A[i]==B[j])
        {
            count=count+1; //It checks how many times equal elements have been found
                           //ensure to declare and initialize int count=0;
        }
    }
}
if(count>=3)
    System.out.println("true");
```

Comment: I suggest that you indent your code to make it easier to read.