# How to avoid repeating myself in nested loops

Tags: c++

I have a method with nested loops like below inside which I do some computationally **expensive** stuff and some computationally **cheap** stuff:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_I; ++i) {
    // Do cheap stuff 1
    // Do computationally expensive stuff 1
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_J; ++j) {
        // Do cheap stuff 2
        // Do computationally expensive stuff 2
        for(int k = 0; k < SIZE_K; ++k) {
            // Do cheap stuff 3
            // Do computationally expensive stuff 3
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I call my method once. But I need to **separate** my cheap stuff from my expensive stuff. The problem is that if I develop **two methods**, I will need to repeat the nested loops and lots of code tangled with them.

I wonder if there is a best practice or tool to help me break my single method into two methods without **repeating** a whole lot of code. Or maybe if there is a solution to separate the cheap from the expensive without the need to break down my single method into two methods?

Comment: why can't you use lambda-expressions?

Comment: What? Could you please make a real example? I have two read twice your question to understand, I guess.

Comment: @gsamaras I can develop a real example. My code is a bit lengthy, let me try ...

Comment: Why not just put each block of code into its own function? That's pretty much what functions are for.

Comment: `std::function` to the rescue! If the airity is different then consider templates. Or consider living with the duplicate code. P.S. Are you sure `int` is an appropriate indexing type?

Comment: No one mentioned *cough* a bool argument to the function with *cough* a default value and some `if` around the expensive stuff...

Comment: @Bathsheba Right. `int` is definitely not the best indexing type. I will take care of it later :)

Comment: @Bathsheba [Huh?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104825/4832499) Not to mention sometimes insane performance penalties.

Comment: @PasserBy: Which for me epitomises why you should never take anything you see on the internet at face value. What about platforms with 16 bit `int` and the ability to allocate larger arrays than 32767?

Comment: @PasserBy: ͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏. Just use a `size_t` or a `ptrdiff_t` if negative values are defined. Pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: @Bathsheba Granted I don't work on embedded platforms, but I've been wrecked by unsigned craziness more than integer overflow. `ptrdiff_t` is fine.

Comment: @Bathsheba Do you often work with arrays of length >32767 but <65535? That extra bit is seldom useful, often harmful. Still waiting for `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Do the various stuffs still need to be executed in order, or is it fine if you end up with twice the loops?

Comment: @PasserBy Your link is a perfect example why raising accepted answer to the top is evil. That accepted answer advocating `unsigned` is a nonsense.

Comment: @Quentin Stuff labeled 1, 2 and 3 are in order and are tangled. The actual code is kind of complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
enum CallStatus {
    CallStatus_Cheap = 0,
    CallStatus_Expensive
};

bool MyClass::MyMethod(MyClass::CallStatus callStatus)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_I; ++i) {

        switch (callStatus) {
        case MyClass::CallStatus_Cheap:
            // Do cheap stuff 1
            break;
        case MyClass::CallStatus_Expensive:
            // Do computationally expensive stuff 1
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE_J; ++j) {

            switch (callStatus) {
            case MyClass::CallStatus_Cheap:
                // Do cheap stuff 2
                break;
            case MyClass::CallStatus_Expensive:
                // Do computationally expensive stuff 2
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < SIZE_K; ++k) {

                switch (callStatus) {
                case MyClass::CallStatus_Cheap:
                    // Do cheap stuff 3
                    break;
                case MyClass::CallStatus_Expensive:
                    // Do computationally expensive stuff 3
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }

// ...

}
```

Making use of `enum` as argument/parameter and `switch`, now I'm able to do **cheap** and **expensive** stuff separately, even though they are very entangled in nested loops.

Comment: BTW you can turn your `CallStatus` parameter into a template parameter if you discover that your `switch` statement is too expensive.

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function which takes functions or lambda expressions as arguments.
It would do the nested loops and apply "cheap stuff" or "expensive stuff" that you passed as parameter.

You would call this once for "cheap stuff" and once for "expensive stuff".

Comment: I didn't occur to me to use lambda. I will give it a try